# Replicar string em determinada parte de um texto (javascript/JQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho um texto e gostaria de replicar strings em determinada parte deste usando javascript ou JQuery

**Texto** = Jo 3:16; 7:1,3; 3.20; Mt 2:3,5,2-7; 3:1; Lc 2:1; 3:12
**O que consigo até agora:** `Jo` 3:16; `Jo` 7:1,3; 3.20; `Mt` 2:3,5,2-7; `Mt` 3:1; `Lc` 2:1; `Lc` 3:12
**Resultado desejado:** `Jo` 3:16; `Jo` 7:1,3; `Jo` 3.20; `Mt` 2:3,5,2-7; `Mt` 3:1; `Lc` 2:1; `Lc` 3:12

Segue abaixo o que tenho conseguido até agora, só consigo adicionar uma sequencia a mais

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  var str = document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML; 
  var res = str
.replace(/(Jo|Mt|Lc) (([0-9]{1,3}(\.|:)[0-9]{1,3}((,| ,|, |-| e )[0-9]{1,3}){1,})|([0-9]{1,3}(\.|:)[0-9]{1,3}))(;|)( [0-9]{1,3}(\.|:))/ig, "$1 $2; $1$10")
.replace(/(Jo|Mt|Lc) (([0-9]{1,3}(\.|:)[0-9]{1,3}((,| ,|, |-| e )[0-9]{1,3}){1,})|([0-9]{1,3}(\.|:)[0-9]{1,3}))(;|)( [0-9]{1,3}(\.|:))/ig, "$1 $2; $1$10")
document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML = res;
//r = document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML = res;
console.log(r)

});
```

```html
<html>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="resultado" id="resultado">
Jo 3:16; 7.1,3; 3:20; Mt 2:3,5,2-7; 3:1; Lc 2:1; 3:12
</div>

</html>
```

Comment: Você pode colocar a string dentro de uma variável, e no texto vc replica essa variável quantas vezes quiser declarando-a nos trechos desejados.

Comment: Eu já consigo colocar em uma variável, o que preciso agora é fazer com que seja distribuído corretamente no texto as strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Segue abaixo como resolvi, pode não ser o código ideal mas serviu

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  var str = document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML; 
  var res = str
.replace(/(Jo|Mt|Lc) (([0-9]{1,3}(\.|:)[0-9]{1,3}((,| ,|, |-| e )[0-9]{1,3}){1,})|([0-9]{1,3}(\.|:)[0-9]{1,3}))(;|)( [0-9]{1,3}(\.|:))/ig, "$1 $2; $1$10")
.replace(/(Jo|Mt|Lc) (([0-9]{1,3}(\.|:)[0-9]{1,3}((,| ,|, |-| e )[0-9]{1,3}){1,})|([0-9]{1,3}(\.|:)[0-9]{1,3}))(;|)( [0-9]{1,3}(\.|:))/ig, "$1 $2; $1$10")
.replace(/(Jo|Mt|Lc) (([0-9]{1,3}(\.|:)[0-9]{1,3}((,| ,|, |-| e )[0-9]{1,3}){1,})|([0-9]{1,3}(\.|:)[0-9]{1,3}))(;|)( [0-9]{1,3}(\.|:))/ig, "$1 $2; $1$10")
.replace(/(Jo|Mt|Lc) (([0-9]{1,3}(\.|:)[0-9]{1,3}((,| ,|, |-| e )[0-9]{1,3}){1,})|([0-9]{1,3}(\.|:)[0-9]{1,3}))(;|)( [0-9]{1,3}(\.|:))/ig, "$1 $2; $1$10")
.replace(/(Jo|Mt|Lc) (([0-9]{1,3}(\.|:)[0-9]{1,3}((,| ,|, |-| e )[0-9]{1,3}){1,})|([0-9]{1,3}(\.|:)[0-9]{1,3}))(;|)( [0-9]{1,3}(\.|:))/ig, "$1 $2; $1$10")
document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML = res;
//r = document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML = res; console.log(r);

});
```

```html
<html>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="resultado" id="resultado">
Jo 3:16; 7.1,3; 3:20; Mt 2:3,5,2-7; 3:1; Lc 2:1; 3:12
</div>

</html>
```